# Appending arrays to a list overwrites existing values

Tags: python, arrays, append, numpy-ndarray

As a newbie in python I want to populate a list with images, in form of arrays. If I add elements, they overwrite the existing values. How can I add elements into a list?

Example code:

```
import numpy as np

ims = []
show_img= np.zeros([2,2,3],dtype=np.uint8)

for x in range(10):
    show_img.fill(x)
    ims.append(show_img)

print(ims)
```

Result:

```
[[[9 9 9]
  [9 9 9]]

 [[9 9 9]
  [9 9 9]]]
```

Expected would be a list with all the elements

EDIT: print(ims) - I wanted to print the whole list

Comment: You've appended 10 references to the same underlying numpy array to your list - `fill()` modifies it in place. One simple way to fix this is to move the `np.zeros` call into your `for` loop so that you get independent arrays. You could also use `numpy.copy` to make a new copy for each iteration.

Comment: you are appending **the same object** `ims.append(show_img)` that you created here: `show_img= np.zeros([2,2,3],dtype=np.uint8)` ten times.

Comment: So I am not appending different arrays, but an object? Ok. Since the values are changing, how can I add a certain state of the object?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper thanks for the tipp with *numpy.copy*, that did the trick. I was not aware that an Image is an object, I thought it was an array.

Comment: @Widhold - arrays are a type of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, you keep modifying and appending the same array.

There's no need to pre-create the array and then fill it with different values. Use [`np.full()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full) to create the array full of `x` values all at once.

```
ims = [np.full([2,2,3], x, dtype=np.uint8) for x in range(10)]
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, this is just the source of my problem. I am generating lots of new Images, and want them to add to one list, to be shown smoothly (in an animation), after all of them are generated

Comment: What's the problem? After you generate all of them with this, you can loop over `ims`. `for image in ims:`

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said, I used numpy.copy to make a copy of the object, than it worked fine (I no longer save the same object):

```
import numpy as np

ims = []
show_img= np.zeros([3,3,3],dtype=np.uint8)

for x in range(10):
    show_img.fill(x)
    ims.append(np.copy(show_img))

print(ims)
```